# Determine the integer roots of the polynomial $P(P(x))$

Tags: polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n\ge 5$ having real coefficients and $n$ distinct integer roots,so that$P(0)=0$,Determine the integer roots of the polynomial $P(P(x))$

Where I am:

Let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ be integer roots.then we have
$$P(x)=A(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})\cdots (x-x_{n})$$
since $P(0)=0$,then we have
$$P(x)=A[(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})\cdots (x-x_{n})-(-1)^nx_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}]$$
then I can't find $P(x)$

Comment: $P(0) =0$ means you can choose $x_1 = 0 $ in your first expression

Answer (score 2):

$P(0)=0$ means

$$P(x) = A x(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$$

$$P(P(x)) = AP(x)(P(x)-x_2)...(P(x) -x_n)$$

$P(P(x)) =0 $ means all the integer roots of $P(x)$ is  also integer roots of $P(P(x))$.

You then ask if there are integers $m_i$ such that $P(m_i) -x_i =0$

$A m_i(m_i-x_2)...(m_i-x_n)-x_i =0$

This is impossible for irrational $A$ by rational root theorem 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

For rational $A=\frac{p}{q}$, the solution depends on $A$. 
Let's say, I randomly pick some integer $m \neq x_i$ for all $i$. If $A =  \frac{x_i}{m(m-x_2)...(m-x_n)} $, then $m$ is a solution.

It seems that it cannot be solved for unspecified $A$